# Page aware Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, yii, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a project that requires precise breadcrumb links.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
Home >> Category(page 2)
Home >> Category(page 2) >> Catalog(page 3)
Home >> Category(page 2) >> Catalog(page 3) >> Actual_product
```

- I've looked around and I've found nothing on page awareness while working on breadcrumbs.
- I've tried using `Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer;` but it doesn't work that easily.
- I've tried getting the page number in the controller but I'm stuck at passing the page number to the next controller without implementing another action to which to post it or adding the page number as a parameter to the action I wish to pass it to.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Would appreciate any tips and pointers in the right direction.

Comment: i am a bit confused, Do you want to include page number, like if you have category listings and have 5 pages of it. and user opened a category on page 4 , you want to include that page number in your breadcrumb like Home >> Category (Page 4) >> Catalog( Page 1) ? or page number in your sample is just a breadcrumb level.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. I want the breadcrumbs to include pagination page numbers, more or less exactly as you explained it. I've done some more searching about this and only found this http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3741-auto-breadcrumbs/
Though it doesn't work quite as expected, it only provides one level of breadcrumbs even though there are settings for it to provide multiple and by the look of the code it should work with multiple breadcrumbs,...